# laravel 7 change authentication users table name and model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm currently using the Laravel 7 authentication in my application; and I want to change the users table name while keeping its role as it is in the authentication logic.. because we have already an users table in our main app, so we have working in another dashboard and users table of the new app will make a conflict.

So any solution please!

Comment: You can change it to whatever model you want

Comment: It's work base on ID so change anything except ID

Comment: You can have a different model say DashboardUser and corresponding table dashboard_users. Then you need to update `config\auth.php` with the values accordingly. Assuming that the app has only one table for users

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that you name the model DashboardUser and table dashboard_users

Then update the values in `config\auth.php`

```php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'dashboard_users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'dashboard_users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'dashboard_users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\DashboardUser::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'dashboard_users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Answer (score 1):

first go to the Model that you want to be your auth model (this in example `Dashboard` is your auth Model so go to the `app/Models/Dashboard.php`) then extends the model from `Authenticatable`.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Dashboard extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

go to the `config/auth.php` file and change default table (users) to new table that you want (this in example new table named `dashboards`).

```
return [ 
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'dashboards',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'dashboards',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'dashboards',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Dashboard::class,
        ],

    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'dashboards',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

*also don't forget change `password_resets` table*